# Application.OnTime on Error Resume Next

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering why the onTime method needs to be preceded by an on Error Resume next Statement.  Obviously its because it raises an error and it doesn't seem to affect it's function but I'm just curious.

Can anybody enlighten me?

Code posted as per request!

this is in a worksheet module:

```
Const scrollRowName = "WindowScrollRow"
Dim ws As DataViewSheetClass
Public nextTime As Double
Public latestTime As Double


Private Sub startDog()
If Me.ProtectContents Then
    nextTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
    If Me.ProtectContents Then Application.OnTime nextTime, Me.CodeName & ".kickDog"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub kickDog()
Static prevWsRow As Long

    If Me Is ActiveSheet And Me.ProtectContents Then
        wsRow = ActiveWindow.scrollRow
        If wsRow <> prevWsRow Then
            With Application
              .screenUpdating = False
              .StatusBar = "Calculating Formats"
              .EnableEvents = False

              scrollRow.Value2 = ActiveWindow.scrollRow

              .EnableEvents = True
              .StatusBar = False

              prevWsRow = wsRow
              .screenUpdating = True
            End With
        End If

        Debug.Print timeStamp & ": Woof!" & Chr(9) & wsRow & Chr(9) & scrollRow.Value2

        nextTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
        latestTime = nextTime + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
        Application.OnTime nextTime, Me.CodeName & ".kickDog", latestTime
    Else
        killDog
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub killDog()
    On Error GoTo rebootObjects
    scrollRow.Value2 = 1
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime nextTime, Me.CodeName & ".Worksheet_Deactivate", latestTime, False
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
rebootObjects:
    Set scrollRow = Me.Range(scrollRowName)
    scrollRow.Value2 = 1
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Debug.Print timeStamp & ": " & "Summary Activate Start:" & Chr(9) & MicroTimer - t
    t = MicroTimer
    On Error GoTo enableAndExit
    Set ws = New DataViewSheetClass
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With ws
        .addedActiveArea = Range("WeeksTable")
        .addedActiveArea = Range("SummaryTotals")
        .SparkTargetBehaviour = HEAVY
    End With

enableAndExit:
    Err.Clear
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Set scrollRow = Me.Range(scrollRowName)
    Set volatileRange = Me.Range(volatileRangeName)
    startDog
    Debug.Print timeStamp & ": " & "Summary Activated:" & Chr(9) & MicroTimer - t
    t = MicroTimer
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    killDog        
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `needs to be preceded` This is the first time I am hearing this :) Where did you read it?

Comment: This is not necessarily true.......post your code.

Comment: I "experienced" it and then I read it here:
 http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/OnTime.aspx
:q

Comment: You misunderstood the article. It doesn't say anywhere `the onTime method NEEDS to be preceded by an on Error Resume next Statement` On certain (Not All) scenarios, yes it is required as shown in that article.

Comment: Hi @Siddharth Rout would you care to elaborate or direct me to a useful source?  I'm still looking for an answer on this.  1. I know the article does not say that the resume next is necessary but it doesn't say why its there. 2. I found it necessary in my case but I'm not sure if its a good idea and would like to know the details on when it is and isn't necessary. 3. Which scenarios necessitate the this?

Comment: Hi @Gary's Student I posted my code as requested, would you care to elaborate?

Comment: I'll review tomorrow (my time)

Comment: @Gary's Student much appreciated! Sorry, I didn't understand about the "@" tag until Mr Siddharth kindly pointed it out to me.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Hi, Don't worry about, it I did some experiments and I think I have it covered now. I'll post back my conclusions later to close off the thread. Thanks anyway for your kind offer!

Comment: Good Job!!........Please update if you get the chance........I have an interest in the solution.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Hi, updated as per your request. I hope its not too rambling for the rules!  I'm sure there are more elegant ways to achieve the same thing so please feel free to critique!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I conducted a series of experiments to try to understand this function better and my results follow.  I'm very pleased to confirm that the educated supposition offered by @Jean-François Corbett ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101352/excel-vba-application-ontime)) was absolutely correct.

1. Yes, you can have more than one timer with the same exact same `EarliestTime` so this argument is NOT equivalent to "a serial number to register the timer" (contrary to my reading elsewhere).
2. You can have the *same* `Procedure` argument on calls with *different* `EarliestTime` arguments and it will also function normally as two separate timers.
3. Both of these arguments, however, must be the same as the initial call (with `Schedule:=True`) when killing the timer (with `Schedule:=False`).  Failing to do so will throw `ERROR: 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error` on trying to execute the OnTime call with `Schedule:=False`.  Also, the timer will not be reset in this case and an `ERROR 1004: Object variable or With block variable not set` will result if the call-back procedure address can not be resolved when the timer triggers.
4. The resolution of the timer is 1 second.  If you try to start two timers 0.5 seconds apart, they will be registered with the same start time.
5. I don't think its wise to use the `LatestTime` argument: I think the timers should always be terminated manually.  Omitting it also ensures that the timer will persist if there is a long save or calculate event that exceeds the timer duration and delays the call-back.
6. Its very important to fully qualify the call-back `Procedure` to ensure that it is resolvable when the timer fires.  Failure to do so may result in the timer not being re-set and the workbook re-opening on attempting to close it, if other workbooks are open at the time.
7. It is possible to create an `OnTimer Class Module` with a call-back `Procedure` referencing a `Worksheet` `Class Module` `Method`.  It's a good idea to ensure that the `Procedure` argument is fully qualified (e.g. `Procedure:="'wb Name.xlsm'!Sheet1.methodName"`).
8. If you use the `Worksheet_Activate` and `Worksheet_Deactivate` events to manage the timer life-cycle and call these procedures from the Workbook_WindowActivate and Workbook_WindowDeactivate events, then the timer will start reliably and the workbook will close and stay closed.  You can also use the Workbook_BeforeClose and Workbook_Open events, but they won't cover switching between Workbooks.  Because of the sequence in which they fire, the window events, in conjunction with the worksheet events will cover everything.
9. You need to use some means of transmitting these events to the active worksheet which is hosting the timer.  This can be done by creating a `Class`, based on `CallByName` to notify the `ActiveSheet` of the workbook events.  You can also do it using a `WorkBook`, `WithEvents` `Class` object declared in the `Worksheet`, but you still need a `CallByName` type call to initiate on `WorkBook_WindowActivate`.
10. Attempting to kill a timer with `OnTime Schedule:=False` *after the timer has triggered* will result in `ERROR: 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error`.
11. Preceding the `OnTime Schedule:=False` call with On Error Resume Next allows for the possibility of killing the timer after it has triggered.  I do so but I always trap errors and I have not seen any errors thrown by the OnTime function that weren't genuine and in need of handling.

In response to interest expressed by Mr @Gary's Student I include Example, working code.

In ThisWorkbook Class Module:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Notify As New cActiveSheetBus

'This is needed to boot the active sheet because the
'Worksheet_Activate event does not fire in the sheet
Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    Notify.onWindowActivate ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

A Class called cActiveSheetBus to provide cross-talk between the WorkBook and Worksheet Class modules:

```
Option Explicit
Const moduleIndent = 2
'Notify Activesheet of Workbook Events
Sub activeSheetCallBack(ws As Worksheet, cb As String)

    On Error GoTo fnCallbackFailed
    CallByName ws, cb, VbMethod
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
fnCallbackFailed:
    Debug.Print cModuleName & vbTab & myName & vbTab & "****failed****"
    Err.Clear
End Sub

Public Sub onOpen(ws As Worksheet)
    activeSheetCallBack ws, "onOpen"
End Sub
Public Sub beforeClose(ws As Worksheet)
    activeSheetCallBack ws, "beforeClose"
End Sub
Public Sub beforeSave(ws As Worksheet)
    activeSheetCallBack ws, "beforeSave"
End Sub
Public Sub afterSave(ws As Worksheet)
    activeSheetCallBack ws, "afterSave"
End Sub
Public Sub onWindowActivate(ws As Worksheet)
    activeSheetCallBack ws, "onWindowActivate"
End Sub
Public Sub onWindowDEActivate(ws As Worksheet)
    activeSheetCallBack ws, "onWindowDEActivate"
End Sub
```

In the Host Worksheet's Class Module (in this case Sheet2)

```
Option Explicit

Const cPulseTime As Long = 1
Const cBackgroundPulse As Boolean = False
Dim mOnTime As cOnTime

'Expose custom worksheet properties to configure the timer (optional)
Property Get pulseTime() As Long
  ' Can put any logic here that interracts with the sheet
  ' or the user or the application for example
  '  pulseTime = cPulseTime
    pulseTime = Me.Range("pulseTime")
End Property
Property Get enableBackgroundPulse() As Boolean
    enableBackgroundPulse = cBackgroundPulse
End Property
Property Get designMode() As Boolean
    designMode = Me.ProtectContents
End Property

'****************************************
'ActiveSheet Call-backs
Public Sub onWindowActivate()
Const cMyName As String = "onWindowActivate"

  Worksheet_Activate

End Sub
'****************************************

'****************************************
'Timer call-back for cOnTime
Public Sub kickDog()
'   Code to execute on timer event
'******************************************
    On Error Resume Next
    Me.Cells(1, 1) = Not Me.Cells(1, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0
'******************************************
    Debug.Print "woof!!"
    On Error GoTo exitError
        mOnTime.kickDog
    On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
exitError:
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Const myName As String = "Sheet2.Worksheet_Activate"
    Debug.Print myName

    If (mOnTime Is Nothing) Then
      Set mOnTime = New cOnTime
    Else
      mOnTime.kickDog
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
Const pName As String = "Sheet2.Worksheet_Deactivate"

End Sub
```

This in a Class Module called cOnTime:

```
Option Explicit
'****************************************
'Encapsulated timer that will sense the active
' sheet and expect to find a callback there
'
'In host sheet
' Const cPulseTime As Long = 1
'
' Dim mOnTime As cOnTime
' Property Get PulseTime() As Long
'     PulseTime = cPulseTime
' End Property
' '****************************************
' 'Timer call-back for cOnTime
' Public Sub kickDog()
' '   Code to execute on timer event
' '******************************************
'     On Error Resume Next
'     Me.Cells(1, 1) = Not Me.Cells(1, 1)
'     On Error GoTo 0
' '******************************************
'     Debug.Print "woof!!"
'     On Error GoTo exitError
'         mOnTime.kickDog
'     On Error GoTo 0
' Exit Sub
' exitError:
' End Sub

Const DEFDoWhen As String = "kickDog"
Const DEFPulseTime = "PulseTime"
Const DEFearliestTime As Long = 5
Const DEFlatestTime As Long = 15

Private WithEvents wb As Workbook
Private Ws As Worksheet

Private DoWhen As String
Dim KillTimer As String
Private mPulseTime As Long
Private mDesignMode
Private mBackgroundPulse
Private mNextTime As Double
Property Let callBackDoWhen(cb As String)
    DoWhen = "'" & wb.Name & "'!" & Ws.CodeName & "." & cb      'e.g. 'wb Name.xlsm'!Sheet1.kickdog
End Property
Property Let callBackPulseTime(csPulseTime As String)
Const cMyName As String = "Let PulseTime"

    On Error Resume Next
         mPulseTime = CallByName(Ws, csPulseTime, VbGet)
         If Err.Number <> 0 Then
             mPulseTime = DEFearliestTime
         End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Property
Private Function wsGetProperty(prop As String, default)
    On Error Resume Next
         wsGetProperty = CallByName(Ws, prop, VbGet)
         If Err.Number <> 0 Then
             wsGetProperty = default
         End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
Private Function pulseTime() As Long
' This is a live connection to the sheet
    pulseTime = wsGetProperty(DEFPulseTime, DEFearliestTime)
End Function
Private Function designMode() As Boolean
' The sheet is only consulted once
  If mDesignMode = Empty Then _
    mDesignMode = wsGetProperty("designMode", False)
  designMode = mDesignMode
End Function
Private Function backgroundPulse() As Boolean
' The sheet is only consulted once
  If mBackgroundPulse = Empty Then _
    mBackgroundPulse = wsGetProperty("enableBackgroundPulse", False)
  backgroundPulse = mBackgroundPulse
End Function
Public Sub kickDog()
Const myName As String = "kickDog"
Dim psMessage As String
    If (Ws Is ActiveSheet Or backgroundPulse) _
        And Not designMode Then

        mNextTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, pulseTime)

        On Error Resume Next
        Application.OnTime mNextTime, DoWhen
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    Exit Sub
End Sub
Public Sub killDog()

    If Ws Is Nothing Or mNextTime = 0 Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime mNextTime, DoWhen, , False
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Dim errorContext As String

Debug.Print "init conTime"

    On Error GoTo enableAndExit
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    On Error GoTo 0

    callBackDoWhen = DEFDoWhen
    callBackPulseTime = DEFPulseTime
    pulseTime
    designMode
    backgroundPulse

    kickDog

    Exit Sub
enableAndExit:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        If Ws Is Nothing Then
            errorContext = "ws"
        ElseIf wb Is Nothing Then
            errorContext = "wb"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
Const myName As String = "Class_Terminate"

    On Error Resume Next
    killDog
    Set Ws = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Exit Sub

End Sub

' Manage the timer in response to workbook events
' If the timer is not killed it may cause the workbook
' to reopen after it is closed when the timer calls back.

Private Sub wb_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
Const myName As String = "cOnTime.wb_WindowActivate"
    Debug.Print myName

   ' this is handled by ThisWorkbook
End Sub

Private Sub wb_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
Const myName As String = "cOnTime.wb_WindowDeactivate"
    Debug.Print myName

    If Not backgroundPulse Then killDog
End Sub
Private Sub wb_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Const myName As String = "cOnTime.wb_BeforeClose"
    Debug.Print myName

    killDog
End Sub

Private Sub wb_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Const myName As String = "cOnTime.wb_BeforeSave"
    Debug.Print myName

    If SaveAsUI Then killDog
End Sub
```

*(No actual dogs were harmed in the making of this code)*

Comment: Undocumented "feature": if the macro of some module leads to the call of `Workbook`'s `Save` or `Close` methods, the `Application.OnTime` called from the `Workbook_BeforeSave` or `Workbook_BeforeClose` event handlers will not schedule the run of the procedure. At the same time, this restriction is not in effect for the Calculate or CellChange events. It was found in Excel 2007/2010.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that, I think I concluded that the Application object is already shut down when it hits BeforeClose. Try running any other Application method and I think it will also fail silently.

Answer (score 0):

Its not required and it's a horribly hacky way to write code.
There are very few scenarios where  "On Error Resume Next" is acceptable.
Here are two to consider:

```
Public function Example1() as Boolean
   dim blnReturnValue as Boolean

   On error goto errHandler

     ... Do stuff here that might error
     ... All code can error!

     blnReturnValue = True  ' Set return flag to success

   cleanExit:
      On Error Resume Next  ' <-- Only Place where "On Error Resume Next" is acceptable
      ... Finalise things here, close objects etc. 

      Example1 = blnReturnValue   ' Return the result

      Exit Function  ' Single Exit point
   errHandler:
      ... Handle the error appropriately here

      Resume CleanExit    ' Ensure the function cleans up after itself
End Function
```

Or if you expect an error but really must continue:

```
Public function Example2() as Boolean
   dim blnReturnValue as Boolean

   On Error Goto errHandler

       blnReturnValue = True  ' default return flag to success

       ... Execute error prone code here
       ... This line will still run after returning from the error handler

       Example2 = blnReturnValue ' Will be False if an error occurred, otherwise true
       Exit Function   'Single Exit Point
   errHandler:
       blnReturnValue = False  ' Set return flag to Failure
       msgbox err.description
       Resume Next   ' Resume at the next line after the error occurred 

End Function
```