# excel vba Application.OnTime

Tags: vba, excel, timer

I asked a question about this last week [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984381/application-ontime-on-error-resume-next) I posted my code as requested but no answer.  Anyway, I have some more specific questions.

When ***resetting*** the timer, what is the purpose of the *Procedure* argument?
It doesn't make sense to have a call-back with `Schedule:=False`.
What happens if the call-back function is no longer in scope for example? Is the timer still reset properly?  Is this why most of the examples I've seen (including Chip Pearson - unfortunately, for some reason I'm not allowed to include the link) proceed the `OnTime` call with `On Error Resume Next`
And, sorry to ask again, but why is this done?

My understanding is that the the timer is registered by the *EarliestTime* argument and that this is the "serial number" for the timer that uniquely identifies it.
Is the *Procedure* argument also included in the registration and subsequent identification process as well?

What happens if the call-back procedure is contained in an object that no longer exists when the timer fires?  Or more generally, what happens if there is some error when the timer fires and tries to execute the call-back procedure?

If the *LatestTime* argument is included, what happens after that time if the timer has not been able to fire?  Does Windows erase the timer completely?

Comment: You didn't get a reply because you didn't address your reply to any one in particular and hence me or Gary didn't get an initimation. You need to add "@" before the name of the person you want to address to.

Answer (score 0):

**My understanding is that the the timer is registered by the EarliestTime argument and that this is the "serial number" for the timer that uniquely identifies it.**

Not sure where you read this? Not that it's a smart thing to do, but you could in principle schedule two or more `OnTime` runs with the same `EarliestTime`. So that doesn't make it unique. The combination of `EarliestTime` and `Procedure` makes it unique.

**When resetting the timer, what is the purpose of the Procedure argument?**

Not sure what you mean by "resetting" the timer; do you mean calling `OnTime` with `Schedule := True` or `Schedule := False`?

Either way, how else is it supposed to know *which* procedure to run (or which procedure run to cancel) if you don't specify the `Procedure` argument? That's what it's for.

I suggest you try it out and convince yourself.

**What happens if the call-back procedure is contained in an object that no longer exists when the timer fires? Or more generally, what happens if there is some error when the timer fires and tries to execute the call-back procedure?**

Well, have you tried it to find out for yourself? Nothing mysterious happens. You get an error message as usual.

**If the LatestTime argument is included, what happens after that time if the timer has not been able to fire? Does Windows erase the timer completely?**

I guess you could put it that way. The procedure won't be run. See VBA help:

> For example, if LatestTime is set to EarliestTime + 30 and Microsoft Excel is not in Ready, Copy, Cut, or Find mode at EarliestTime because another procedure is running, Microsoft Excel will wait 30 seconds for the first procedure to complete. If Microsoft Excel is not in Ready mode within 30 seconds, the procedure won’t be run.

Comment: Hi @Jean-François Corbett thanks for the reply.
I read it here:  http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/OnTime.aspx

"Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat,Schedule:=True" ... 

"You can think of the RunWhen value as a unique key into the OnTime settings."

Comment: I don't see any responses in my post?... It's fine to edit an answer if you are adding details to that answer -- but don't add extra questions or points of discussion in there.

Comment: OK, looks like they deleted my response. I had responses to your points interspersed. I guess that's against the rules.  Hmmm OK, lesson learned...